# How to check the root cause of slow ingestion rate by mlcp?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

At some days the ingestion rates are really good while on other days it's pathetic. How can I find the causes of mlcp ingestion rates slow?
MarkLogic - 8

Comment: are you running a transform? are the document sizes and counts the same or varying?

Comment: More details would be needed to help diagnose. Is there other activity on the cluster competing for resources? Are you loading documents with a transform, or straight inserts? How many threads are you using, and how many threads are available on the appserver(are requests queueing)? Take a look at the meters data in the history app http://yourserver:8002/history/ to see if you can correlate the slow ingestion timeframe with anything that stands out in the charts, like merge activity, higher IO Wait in CPU, appserver request rates and latency, etc

Comment: I have entire job ran docs size and counts

Comment: Cluster doesn't seem to be competing for resources the CPU, IO wait etc. looks fine

Comment: Are there any suspicious messages in the ErrorLog? If running a transform or if triggers are used, could you be competing for locks? Look for XDMP-DEADLOCK that might explain extra execution time if transactions are restarting. Look at the execution times for requests to the appserver you are loading docs.

Comment: The error logs are flooded with XDMP-DEADLOCK but I guess that nornal isn't ?

Comment: no, getting flooded with XDMP-DEADLOCK is not normal. can you post the MLCP command you're running? that might help us spot something

Comment: https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/17/16/understanding-xdmp-deadlock